# Отметка, в каком поле найдено значение

Tags: mysql, sql, база-данных

Мне нужно что то вроде метки, в каком поле было найдено значение искомое, если в нескольких - соответственно несколько меток.

К примеру есть запрос

```
SELECT * FROM `table` 
WHERE (CONVERT(`a` USING utf8) LIKE '%$id%' 
OR CONVERT(`b` USING utf8) LIKE '%$id%' 
OR CONVERT(`c` USING utf8) LIKE '%$id%' )
```

И вот чтобы на выходе я получил не только значения таблицы, но и какие то метки, о том что значение было найдено в полях a и c.

Ответ верный но чуть чуть иначе.

```
select *, concat(case when a LIKE '%$id%' then 'a' else '' end,
          case when b LIKE '%$id%' then 'b' else '' end,
          case when c LIKE '%$id%' then 'c' else '' end)  fields
FROM `table` 
WHERE (CONVERT(`a` USING utf8) LIKE '%$id%' 
OR CONVERT(`b` USING utf8) LIKE '%$id%' 
OR CONVERT(`c` USING utf8) LIKE '%$id%' )
```

Comment: что то типа `select if(CONVERT(a USING utf8) LIKE '%$id%',1,0) as in_a, if(CONVERT(b USING utf8) LIKE '%$id%',1,0) as in_b,...` подойдет ? И если так жутко приходиться искать некий ID - то у вас структура базы скорее всего неправильная

Comment: Ну то я просто вставил $id =) 
А по сути там слова через запятую идут.

Comment: Попробую ваш вариант

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
select *, concat(case when a LIKE '%$id%' then 'a' else '' end, ' ',
          case when b LIKE '%$id%' then 'b' else '' end, ' ',
          case when c LIKE '%$id%' then 'c' else '' end)  fields
FROM `table` 
WHERE (CONVERT(`a` USING utf8) LIKE '%$id%' 
OR CONVERT(`b` USING utf8) LIKE '%$id%' 
OR CONVERT(`c` USING utf8) LIKE '%$id%' )
```

Comment: Вроде бы то что нужно, но почему то на выходе fields всегда null

Comment: Замените concat на concat_ws

Comment: Я подправил решение. Должно работать и без concat_ws.

Comment: Спасибо. Я уже дополнил вопрос, собственно подправил ваш ответ.